# Gravity and Collision with Walls - PYGAME

Tags: python, pygame

When player colliding with the wall it jump to the top of the wall. The methode worked fine with colliding with floor obstacle. But I cant see why collision with wall decrease my player.rect.y coordinate.

```
class player_jump:
 def __init__(self):
    self.jump = False
    self.in_aire = True
    self.vel_y = 0

 def move_y(self):
        #reset movment variables
        dy = 0

        if self.jump and not self.in_air:
            self.vel_y = -11
            self.jump = False
            self.in_air = True

        #apply gravity (global variable , GRAVITY = 0.5 )
        self.vel_y += GRAVITY
        if self.vel_y > 10:
            self.vel_y = 0
   
        dy += self.vel_y

        #check for collision (world.obstacle_list - contain data on wall and bottom rects)
        for tile in world.obstacle_list:
            #x direction
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x + dx,self.rect.y,self.rect.width,self.rect.height):
                dx = 0
              
            #y direction
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x,self.rect.y + dy,self.rect.width,self.rect.height):
                #check if below the ground , i.e jumping
                if self.vel_y < 0:
                    self.vel_y = 0
                    dy = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
                    self.in_air = False
                #check if above the ground i.e falling
                elif self.vel_y >= 0:
                    self.in_air = False
                    dy = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
                    
        # update rectangle position
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
```

Comment: why do you use `self.img.get_width()` instead of `self.rect.width` and the same for `height`?

Comment: are the other tiles moving on their own? like does at some point the player itself doesn't change its coordinates but all of the tiles change their position? because you may need to account for that too

Comment: @Matiiss fixed that to self.rect.width and height. the tiles do change thier position. When they not - its not happen. but still cant understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm depends on the order of the tiles. Make the algorithm order independent for collision detection along the axis.

First run the collision check along the x-axis for all tiles. Then run the collision check along the y-axis for all tiles. When running the test along the y-axis, you also need to account for movement along the x-axis:

```py
# x direction
test_rect = self.rect.move(dx, 0)
for tile in world.obstacle_list:
    if tile[1].colliderect(test_rect):
        dx = 0
        break
              
# y direction
for tile in world.obstacle_list:
            
    test_rect = self.rect.move(dx, dy)
    if tile[1].colliderect(test_rect):
        # [...]
```